# Why won't my app ask or allow location permissions?

Tags: java, android, mobile, geolocation

I have been stuck on this issue for some time. I am trying to make my app request 2 permissions at once, as so:

```java
ibTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //this get image and location and then display both
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            HomePageActivity.this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
            REQUEST_CODE_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION
        );
    }
});
```

So the idea is when the button is clicked the user is prompted to give location and camera permissions, so I can then store the location and photo somewhere. The camera functions work fine, but I am still stuck on getting the location. here is my `onRequestPermissionsResult`:

```java
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (grantResults.length > 0) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            getCurrentLocation();
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                HomePageActivity.this,
                "Location and Camera permissions must be granted for this app to work.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure it's just a problem with these methods, any help would be massively appreciated.

I have tried other ways, such as in my previous question [Java Android - Requesting multiple permissions but one doesn't get requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70602255/java-android-requesting-multiple-permissions-but-one-doesnt-get-requested/70602540#70602540)

Comment: Did you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> to your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

When requesting `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` you also need to ask for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`.

> To handle this potential user behavior, don't request the
> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission by itself. Instead, request both the
> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission and the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
> permission in a single runtime request. If you try to request only
> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, the system ignores the request if you app target Android 12 or above.
> Blockquote

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest ... >
  <!-- Always include this permission -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

  <!-- Include only if your app benefits from precise location access. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

Java code

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(HomePageActivity.this, 
                                     new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                                          REQUEST_CODE_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION
                                                  );
```

You can find more info on google docs - [Request location permission](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#types-of-access)